# Paypal update recurring payment

Tags: java, paypal

I use PayPal's `UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile` API Operation to update existing a PayPal recurring payment. When I called the `PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService` to update the recurring payment using `UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequest`, it took some time then returned with this response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:cc="urn:ebay:apis:CoreComponentTypes" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xmlns:ns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <Security xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xsi:type="wsse:SecurityType" />
  <RequesterCredentials xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI" xsi:type="ebl:CustomSecurityHeaderType">
     <Credentials xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xsi:type="ebl:UserIdPasswordType">
        <Username xsi:type="xs:string">xxx</Username>
        <Password xsi:type="xs:string">xxx</Password>
        <Signature xsi:type="xs:string">xxx</Signature>
        <Subject xsi:type="xs:string" />
     </Credentials>
  </RequesterCredentials>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body id="_0">
  <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
     <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
     <faultstring>Timeout processing request</faultstring>
  </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

here's also the code I use:

```
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().toString());

    UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfileReq updateRecurringPaymentsProfileReq = new UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfileReq();

    UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestType updateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestType = new UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestType();
    updateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestType.setVersion("63.0");

    UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetailsType updateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetailsType = new UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetailsType();
    updateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetailsType.setProfileID(farmBoxOrder.getProfileId());

    BasicAmountType basicAmountType = new BasicAmountType();
    basicAmountType.setValue(Utilities.stringfyDoubleValue(farmBoxOrder.getFarmBoxSize().getPrice()));

    updateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetailsType.setAmount(basicAmountType);

    BillingPeriodDetailsType_Update billingPeriodDetailsTypeUpdate = new BillingPeriodDetailsType_Update();
    billingPeriodDetailsTypeUpdate.setAmount(basicAmountType);
    billingPeriodDetailsTypeUpdate.setBillingFrequency(farmBoxOrder.getFrequency());

    BillingPeriodType billingPeriodType = null;

    if(farmBoxOrder.getFrequencyUnit().equals(FrequencyUnitEnum.DAY))
    {
        billingPeriodType = BillingPeriodType.DAY;
    }
    else if(farmBoxOrder.getFrequencyUnit().equals(FrequencyUnitEnum.WEEK))
    {
        billingPeriodType = BillingPeriodType.WEEK;
    }
    else if(farmBoxOrder.getFrequencyUnit().equals(FrequencyUnitEnum.MONTH))
    {
        billingPeriodType = BillingPeriodType.MONTH;
    }
    else if(farmBoxOrder.getFrequencyUnit().equals(FrequencyUnitEnum.YEAR))
    {
        billingPeriodType = BillingPeriodType.YEAR;
    }
    billingPeriodDetailsTypeUpdate.setBillingPeriod(billingPeriodType);

    updateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetailsType.setPaymentPeriod(billingPeriodDetailsTypeUpdate);;

    updateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestType.setUpdateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetails(updateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetailsType);
    updateRecurringPaymentsProfileReq.setUpdateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequest(updateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestType);

    PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService service = null;
    try {

        InputStream is = PaypalService.class
                .getResourceAsStream("/sdk_config.properties");

        service = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService(is);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.severe("Error Message : " + e.getMessage());
    }
    UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponseType updateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponseType = null;
    try {
        // ## Making API call
        // Invoke the appropriate method corresponding to API in service
        // wrapper object
        updateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponseType = service
                .updateRecurringPaymentsProfile(updateRecurringPaymentsProfileReq);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.severe("Error Message : " + e.getMessage());
    }

    // ## Accessing response parameters
    // You can access the response parameters using getter methods in
    // response object as shown below
    // ### Success values
    if (updateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponseType.getAck().getValue()
            .equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {

        // A unique identifier for future reference to the details of
        // this recurring payment.
        logger.info("Profile ID:"
                + updateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponseType
                        .getUpdateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponseDetails()
                        .getProfileID());
    }
    // ### Error Values
    // Access error values from error list using getter methods
    else {
        List<ErrorType> errorList = updateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponseType
                .getErrors();
        logger.severe("API Error Message : "
                + errorList.get(0).getLongMessage());
    }
```

...where `farmBoxOrder` is a bean that store the data needed to creates/modify recurring billing.

Here's the request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI" xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xmlns:cc="urn:ebay:apis:CoreComponentTypes" xmlns:ed="urn:ebay:apis:EnhancedDataTypes">
<soapenv:Header>
<ns:RequesterCredentials>
<ebl:Credentials>
<ebl:Username>XXXXXXX</ebl:Username>
<ebl:Password>XXXXXXX</ebl:Password>
<ebl:Signature>XXXXXXX</ebl:Signature>
</ebl:Credentials>
</ns:RequesterCredentials>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
<ns:UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfileReq>
<ns:UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequest>
<ebl:Version>63.0</ebl:Version>
<ebl:UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetails>
<ebl:ProfileID>XXXXXXXX</ebl:ProfileID>
<ebl:PaymentPeriod>
<ebl:BillingPeriod>Week</ebl:BillingPeriod>
<ebl:BillingFrequency>1</ebl:BillingFrequency>
<ebl:Amount>29.00</ebl:Amount>
</ebl:PaymentPeriod>
</ebl:UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetails>
</ns:UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequest>
</ns:UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfileReq>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

username. password, signature and profileId are set correctly, I just removed them for security.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the request you're sending?

Comment: I edit the post to add the request @AndrewAngell

Comment: when update only shipping address, it works, but when update amount, frequency or period it gives that error, the problem is that the error doesn’t describe if there's any limitation for update recurring payment profile

Comment: I think maybe your XML elements are off..??  Are you sure Amount is supposed to be a child of PaymentPeriod?

Comment: yes, I'm sure, it's according to paypal API

Comment: What doc are you looking at?  The [API reference](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_SOAP/) looks like Amount should go under the root of the request.

Comment: well, you're right, but if you take another look at the doc, you will see the amount also is under PaymentPeriod, anyway I tries them both (together and respectively) and it still not working, I also find this note: "For recurring payments with Express Checkout, the payment amount can be increased by no more than 20% every 180 days (starting when the profile is created)", I'm fine with that, but if that's the problem why payapl doesn't return more descriptive error message, is it a bug in paypal, or something I did wrong?

Comment: You should be getting a better error.  "timeout" or "internal error" typically means either something is actually wrong with their server (which should only happen very rarely) or there's something wrong with the format of the API request.  I always work with NVP so I don't have any working samples of XML calls to compare to.  You could post your sample to www.paypal.com/mts and they can help you figure out what's wrong.